# Magento static Blocks is not displaying properly.

Tags: php, magento

**I have created few static blocks just based on the category Id trying to display different blocks** .

- The problem being some times the block is displayed while some other times it is not .
- I guess there is prob with code ? or the way magneto displays static blocks  not sure ?

**CODE:**

```
<?php

<?php $_description = $this->getProduct()->getDescription(); ?>
<?php if ($_description): ?>
    <div class="std">
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($this->getProduct(), $_description, 'description') ?>
        <?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();?>
<?php if($category->getId()==14): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('products_information')->toHtml();?>
<?php elseif($category->getId()==15): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('products_information')->toHtml();?>
<?php elseif($category->getId()==16): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('products_information')->toHtml();?>
<?php elseif($category->getId()==18): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('products_information')->toHtml();?>
<?php elseif($category->getId()==19): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('products_information')->toHtml();?>
<?php elseif($category->getId()==86): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('products_information')->toHtml();?>
<?php elseif($category->getId()==25): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('products_information')->toHtml();?>
<?php elseif($category->getId()==13): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('products_information')->toHtml();?>
<?php elseif($category->getId()==98): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('products_information_fbyz')->toHtml();?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('products_information_others')->toHtml();?>
<?php endif; ?>

    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**please resolve my problem.**

Comment: are you code out this code on product view page???

Comment: Yes on products view page trying to display additional information about the products

Answer (score 0):

If you put this code in `product view page` then it it not properly way to get current category in product page..
Used `Mage::registry("current_category")` instead of `Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()`;

If you come to category directly then you can get  current category id product page.then you used to fetch current product categories ids.

```
    $categoryIds = Mage::registry('current_product')->getCategoryIds();
    if(Mage::registry("current_category"))
    {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->load(Mage::registry("current_category")->getId());
    }elseif(is_array($categoryIds )){
        //multiple categories id of product. that way i was taken on list category
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds[0]);
    }
    elseif(!is_null($categoryIds)){
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds);

    }
    else{
        //no categoies
    }
```

Comment: Sorry cant figure it out properly  . Based on the category id or array of category  Id , I want to display a specified static block from backend . Any small example based on my category id's will be of great help !